# Multiple LEFT JOIN doesn't work on SUM()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So the idea is to get information from 3 tables:

1. R_Regle: rule table, basic info of the rule
2. C_Commentaire: the **number of comments** this rule has
3. I_Interet: The **SUM of all** upvotes and downvotes from one rule.

The structure of my I_Interet: 
I_ID / I_Idregle / I_Idpseudo / I_Upvote / I_Downvote

Each row can only contain 1 upvote or 1 downvote.

so with this request:

```
    SELECT R_Id, R_Date, R_Titre, R_Contenu, R_Etape, COUNT(C_Commentaire.C_IdRegle) AS CountComment, SUM(I_Interet.I_Up) AS Up ,SUM(I_Interet.I_Down) AS Down 
    FROM R_Regle
            LEFT JOIN C_Commentaire ON C_Commentaire.C_IdRegle = R_Regle.R_Id
            LEFT JOIN I_Interet ON I_Interet.I_IdRegle = R_Regle.R_Id 
     GROUP BY R_ID
```

I try to obtain all those information.

Problem is:

```
COUNT(C_Commentaire.C_IdRegle) AS CountComment
```

Gives me the count of all COMMENTS and UPVOTES/DOWNVOTES.

So if there are 4 comments and 3 downvotes, it will count it like that

```
 $row['CountComment'] = 7;
```

But obviously, I don't want that. I want

```
$row['CountComment'] = 4;
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

Here are the tables:

R_REGLE

```
CREATE TABLE `R_Regle` (
  `R_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `R_Auteur` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `R_Date` date NOT NULL,
  `R_Titre` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `R_Contenu` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `R_Etape` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 = discussion 2= VOTE',
  PRIMARY KEY (`R_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

C_COMMENTAIRE

```
CREATE TABLE `C_Commentaire` (
  `C_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `C_Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `C_Pseudo` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_Contenu` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `C_IdRegle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`C_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I_INTERET

```
CREATE TABLE `I_Interet` (
  `I_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `I_IdRegle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `I_Pseudo` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `I_Up` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `I_Down` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`I_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Do `I_Up` and `I_Down` these two fields contain either 0 or 1?

Comment: Yes ! Maximum 1 vote per rule per user. So it's either an Upvote either a Downvote. but not both or not more than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest using correlated query.. not sure if thats what you want since you didn't post any table structures its hard to know :

```
SELECT R_Id, R_Date, R_Titre, R_Contenu, R_Etape,
       (select COUNT(*) from C_Commentaire where C_Commentaire.C_IdRegle = R_Regle.R_Id) AS CountComment, 
       SUM(I_Interet.I_Up) AS Up ,
       SUM(I_Interet.I_Down) AS Down 
FROM R_Regle
        LEFT JOIN I_Interet ON I_Interet.I_IdRegle = R_Regle.R_Id 
GROUP BY R_ID
```

Comment: prntscr.com/a6gl4o Here is the table structure ! I edited my first post with all the CREATE table code ! I'm gonna try what you gave :)

Comment: IT DID !  Thanks a lot ! Thats an odd structure but i'm gonna look into it. Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: No problem.. I think you could also change your query to count(distinct c_commentaire.cid) and it will do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Write your query as below:

```
SELECT R_Regle.R_Id, R_Regle.R_Date, R_Regle.R_Titre, R_Regle.R_Contenu, R_Regle.R_Etape, 
COUNT(C_Commentaire.C_IdRegle) AS CommentCounts, 
SUM(I_Interet.I_Up) AS Up,
SUM(I_Interet.I_Down) AS Down 
FROM R_Regle
    LEFT JOIN C_Commentaire ON R_Regle.R_Id = C_Commentaire.C_IdRegle 
    LEFT JOIN I_Interet ON R_Regle.R_Id = I_Interet.I_IdRegle 
GROUP BY R_Regle.R_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

In your query there are duplicate records arisen when you make a left join among the three tables.

The following query is one of few ways to achieve your desired result.

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    SUM(I_Interet.I_Up) AS Up,
    SUM(I_Interet.I_Down) AS Down
FROM
    (    
                SELECT 
                        R_Id,
                        R_Date,
                        R_Titre,
                        R_Contenu,
                        R_Etape,
                        COUNT(c_commentaire.C_IdRegle) countComment

                FROM
                R_Regle LEFT JOIN C_Commentaire ON C_Commentaire.C_IdRegle = R_Regle.R_Id
                GROUP BY R_Regle.R_Id ) t

LEFT JOIN I_Interet ON I_Interet.I_IdRegle = t.R_Id
GROUP BY t.R_Id
```

Comment: would you please post your related table structures? I mean post your `create table code`

Comment: I've edited my inital post with all the create table code, here is a prt scrn of the structure http://prntscr.com/a6gl4o

Comment: in case i'm not clear, here are the two possible scenarios : http://prntscr.com/a6gpgv

Comment: sorry I forgot to add `GROUP BY R_Regle.R_Id` in the inner query. @user3089871